# Inverse Limit of Compact Connected Covering Spaces

Tags: general-topology

It is known that the figure 8 space (denoted by $U$) has a universal covering space, and hence the inverse limit for all its connected covering spaces would be the universal cover. However, if we only consider the inverse limit of all compact connected covering spaces of $U$, since it is a closed subspace of a compact Hausdorff space, it must also be compact.

So, my question is: what would this space look like? Is it the one-point compactification of the universal cover? If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: It's definitely not the 1-point compactification of the universal cover; it's something far more exotic.  If you do this construction with a circle rather than a figure 8 space, you get a [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thanks! How about I change the question so that you can turn the comment into a more concrete answer?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem here: which inverse limit do you mean? We can do the inverse limit in the category of topological spaces or the inverse limit in the category of coverings of U. I guess that they are different spaces. The map of the first one onto U may not be a covering map. We have also that the second one may not be compact. In the example of the circle, the second inverse limit is the universal compactification (given by the intersection of all finite index subgroups of the fundamental group, which is, in this case, the trivial group).

Comment: *universal covering

Comment: @LucasHenrique You mean we don't have uniqueness of inverse limit until we specify the category that we are working in?

Comment: @wsxmble, yes. The example of the circle shows that these inverse limits (of the different categories) may not be homeomorphic.